# Add header files to cythonize a c++ class

Tags: python, c++, cython, distutils

I'm pretty new to cython (and c++), and I'm trying to build some simple DSP tools in a modular framework. I want to be able to use them for research purposes in python, and whilst I've successfully managed to translate a number of simple c++ classes into python I'm now struggling with a seemingly trivial problem.

I've written a biquad filtering class defined by biquad.h and biquad.cpp. The idea is to have a number of filtering classes that live in a dsp module, along with a number of other dsp tools (similar to the module organisation in JUCE). In following this approach the biquad header file is not explicitly included in the biquad c++ file, but is rather linked through dsp.h, which defines the module, i.e. in dsp.h I have a list of includes for all dsp classes.

e.g...

```
#include filters/biquad.h
#include filters/fir.h
#include transforms/hilbert.h
```

When I come to build my python object I therefore attempt to compile my biquad filter class:

```
# distutils: sources = biquad.cpp
```

If I try to define my external from the biquad.h file, e.g:

```
cdef extern from "biquad.h":
     cdef cppclass biquad:
```

then I run into problems because the header file isn't included in the c++ file. But if I define the external from the main dsp.h file, e.g:

```
cdef extern from "dsp.h":
     cdef cppclass biquad:
```

it also fails to include the header file. I would have thought that the include statement in the dsp.h would have done this, but it doesn't seem to be the case, and I have no idea how to include it explicitly.

BTW the errors I get are:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'biquad'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "it" failed, which stage do you mean by "it"? The Cython stage (ie compiling pyx -> C/C++) or the compilation stage (compiling C/C++ to an executable)?

Comment: First, header files should declare structs, classes, and functions that are meant to be used elsewhere in the program-- leave the actual implementation/definitions in the .cpp file (which it appears you're already doing :) )

Second, you should include `biquad.h` in `biquad.cpp`. By the way, the convention is to use '.hpp' or '.hxx' for C++ header files. Technically '.h' is for C.

Third, we need to know where exactly the compiler is giving you that error of "undeclared identifier 'biquad'"-- which file does it say?

Comment: Thanks for response sorry for delay I thought I'd get email notification of response....!

Comment: Sorry for delay I thought I'd get email notification of response....! (1) I think it's failing in the compilation stage. (2) Does **biquad.h** not get included via **biquad.cpp**? Do I also need to add it explicitly to **biquad.h**? In normal Xcode I don't need to do this but I guess this is different! (3) It's giving me the error when it tries to compile **biquad.cpp**.

Comment: I tried adding **biquad.h** to **biquad.cpp**, and this compiles giving me my python object. The problem then comes when I try to include it into my python session and I get _ImportError: Symbol not found_. Note that if I simply compile and import outside of my "modular" file structure then everything works fine! Thanks for the help guys, and sorry if I sound a bit incoherent!